# How to map UUID value from Json to Java object using Jackson Object Mapper?

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I'm getting below exception in my testcases

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot 
  deserialize value of type java.util.UUID from String "361236": UUID has to be 
  represented by standard 36-char representation at [Source: (String)"{
    "flowId" : "54947df8-0e9e-4471-a2f9-9af509fb5889",
    "rowId" : 361236
  }
```

I am trying to map my UUID value from Json to Java class using jackson Object mapper, thus i used `"flowId" : "${UUID.fromString("54947df8-0e9e-4471-a2f9-9af509fb5889")}"`,

My Testcase coding below:

```
 `@Test
  fun `test to get onboardGql Converter`() {
    val input="""
       {
             "flowId" : "${UUID.fromString("54947df8-0e9e-4471-a2f9- 
         9af509fb5889")}",
             "rowId" : 361236
     }"""

 val MyClass=jacksonObjectMapper().readValue<MyClass>(input);
}
```

Comment: The error message shows that the problem is when deserializing the value 361236, i.e. the value of rowId, not flowId. rowId should be an int or a long, not a UUID.

Comment: Oh damn. not checked properly.. Thanks